# QGIS Legend element order moving when using custom symbols

Tags: qgis, legend, layouts

On QGIS 3.28.14, I have a strange thing happening my legend element even in a simple map layout.

Say I have simple two layers, both of them have a rule-based symbology.
[image]

In a map layout, I create a legend element and all the symbols are set to use a personalized symbol.

[image]

But when I change anything at all in one of the two layers (adding a new rule or moving the order of the rules), the symbol in the legend gets wrong and symbols does not follow their respective label.

[image]
[image]

Is there something I can do to correct this behavior ?